# A $\sigma$-algebra is a monotone class.

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble understanding the first line of a proof.

"Suppose $A_0$ is an algebra, $A$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $A_0$, and $M$ is the smallest monotone class containing $A_0$, The $M=A$.

Proof.

A $\sigma$-algebra is clearly a monotone class, so $M \subset A$."

I would think that we would have the opposite inclusion. A truck is a car, so {Trucks} $\subset$ {Cars}?

Comment: ...Hence the smallest truck A is larger than the smallest car M. QED.

Comment: I don't get it...

Comment: By your own remark-analogy, {Trucks} ⊂ {Cars} and M = inf {Cars} and A = inf {Trucks}, hence you are done.

Comment: $A$ is sigma algebra, so it's a monotone class. $M$ is the $smallest$ monotone class  that contains $A_0$. Hence...

Comment: Thank you both.